# how do I use chef to force ubuntu to install dependencies?

Tags: java, chef

New to chef.

I'm trying to install openjdk-6-jre-headless using chef, but first I went to try it out using apt-get and I get this this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
openjdk-6-jre-headless: Depends: openjdk-6-jre-lib (>= 6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~10.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: ca-certificates-java but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: tzdata-java but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: java-common (>= 0.28) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.3) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: icedtea-6-jre-cacao (= 6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~10.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

I know I could install each of those items by hand, but using chef-solo how would I automate all this. that is how could I get chef to install openjdk-6-jre-headless and install ALL the dependencies at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is write into your recipe:

```
package 'openjdk-6-jre-headless'
```

Chef will install dependencies automatically.

See [the documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html#id150) on the 'package' resource.

Answer (score 0):

The Chef apt provider adds the `-y` option to command lines so that all prompts are answered with "yes" and the command can run non-interactively.